# Replace space with semicolon when more than one with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying for about 2 hours, and I'm not sure whether what I want to do even works.

I have a large file with some data that looks like

```
43034452      LONGSHIRTPAIETTE                                        17.30
               27.90                                    
                                             0110             


          COLOR               :                    :                    :                    :                    :
                :                    :                    :                    
             -11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
43034453      LONG SHIRT PAI ETTE                                              16.40
               25.90                                    
                                             0110             


          COLOR               :                    :                    :                    :                    :
                :                    :                    :                    
              -3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
43034454      BASIC                                                     4.99
                8.90                                    
                                             0110             


          COLOR               :                    :                    :                    :                    :
                :                    :                    :                    
              -5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

(The file has 36k rows.)

What I want to do is to get this whole thing clean.

In the end, the rows should look like

```
43034452;LONGSHIRTPAIETTE;17.30;27.90;0110
43034453;LONG SHIRT PAI ETTE;16.40;25.90;0110
43034454;BASIC;4.99;8.90;0110
```

So there is a lot of data that I don't need. I'm using Notepad++ to do my regex.

My regex string looks like `([0-9]*)\s{6,}([A-Z]*)\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*([0-9]*)` at the moment.

This brings me the first number followed by 6 spaces. (It has to be like this because some rows start with `FF` and `FF` are not letters. It's some kind of sign that I can't identify but if I let Notepad++ show all signs I see `FF`.)

So as a result I get

```
\1: 43034452
\2: LONGSHIRTPAIETTE
\3: 17.30
\4: 27.90
\5: 0110
```

like expected, but on the next row it stops on the space. If I add `\s` to the pattern, then it also selects all spaces after the word part. And I obviously can't say "only one space", can I?

So my question is, can I use regex to get a selection like the one I want?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
([0-9]+)\s{6,}((?:[A-Z]+\ )+)\s*([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9]+)
```

Note a few things:

- Tightening the `*`s to `+` where this is appropriate, so you're enforcing some characters in those columns, or actual whitespace
- The use of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) to repeat one or more instances of *a word then a space*.

Comment: gues I will go with this one because in this case I have only one space at the end of the last word. :)

Comment: Is there a possibility to also look for a comma in the word ? Because I have a word like: `foo,,bar` and the comma's can stay like they are...

Comment: @Dwza - sure, just add it to the characters, i.e. use `[A-Z,]+`

Comment: This is what I was trying but no matter what I do, it doesn't match this rows... :( see [this sample](https://regex101.com/r/vU7tB9/2)

Comment: aaarrrg... that no comma ^^ it a other sign. sorry ;D

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex

```
([0-9]*)\s{6,}([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*([0-9]*).*?(?=\n\S|$)
```

and then replace the match with `\1;\2;\3;\4;\5`

Don't forget to enable the DOTALL modifier `s`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uZ8rE0/2)

Comment: this pattern also matches the row with color. Actually its nice because thr spaces after the last word is cut of but there are to many rows selected

Comment: but it gives you the expected output.

Comment: Since there are more rows selected then I want... than no :) because if i replace data with lets say semikolon, than I change data "that I don't need" and that makes it another task to select this and remove it :) So it's a Yes and a No. That's why I gave you a 1+

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct.. just replace `*` with `+` (more than one) in your regex.

```
/([0-9]+)\s{6,}([A-Z ]+)\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9]+)/g
```

See the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uH8pK2/2).

Comment: this seems to work online but not in notepad++ if i use this one it skips a lot of rows, than suttenly it take 2 rows and skipps some more rows...

Comment: please check the updated regex.. I missed space in `([A-Z ]+)`

Comment: Actually ok, but the spaces at the end of the last word aren't cut of.

Comment: can you check this? `([0-9]+)\s{6,}([A-Z ]+)\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9]+)(?=\s)` This should give you zero spaces after last word.

Comment: same result :) bat thx, I have accepted nicks answere. That helped me most. Thank you for your tries :)